# Is there a way to compute gradients on unstructured coordinates with Numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, derivative, differentiation, finite-difference

I have a 3D array of data `A`, with shape `(NX, NY, NZ)` in the `x`, `y`, and `z` dimensions, respectively.

I want to find the gradient of `A` in the `y` dimension. This can be done easily with NumPy:

`dAdy = np.gradient(A, Y, axis=1)`

where `Y` is a 1D vector of coordinates in the `y` dimension.

However, this becomes nontrivial if `Y` is unstructured. That is, every "column" of data at fixed positions `(x, z) = (Xi, Zi)` has a unique set of `y` coordinates. For example:

```
A = np.random.random((10, 10, 10))

X = np.arange(10)
Y = np.sort(np.random.random((10, 10, 10)), axis=1)
Z = np.arange(10)
```

The result above is a 3D dataset `A`, defined on a structured set of `X` and `Z` coordinates, while the value of the `Y` coordinate is unique for every data point (but is of course monotonic in the `y` dimension). I want to estimate `dA/dy` via finite differences.

Essentially, I'm trying to take the gradient of many independent columns. Is there a way to vectorize this with NumPy? I tried the following iterative approach, but it's very slow:

```
# A is the 3D dataset
# Y is the 3D dataset with shape matching that of A; gives the y-position of each datapoint in A
NX, NY, NZ = A.shape[0], A.shape[1], A.shape[2]
dA_dy = np.zeros((NX, NY, NZ))
for i in range(NX):
    for k in range(NZ):
        dA_dy[i, :, k] = np.gradient(A[i,:,k], Y[i,:,k])
```

I also thought that I could get smart by implementing the chain rule:

```
dA_dy = np.gradient(A, axis=1) / np.gradient(Y, axis=1)
```

But for the following simple test, this approach does not work:

```
g = np.array([1, 5, 6, 10])  # an unstructured coordinate
f = g**2                     # function value on the points x
grad1 = np.gradient(f, g)                # df/dg
grad2 = np.gradient(f) / np.gradient(g)  # df/dg?
```

I only get `grad1=grad2` for a few simple linear functions, but not the function represented above. I'm now wondering if there is a theoretical reason why the chain rule shouldn't hold in general for derivatives estimated by finite differences.

Comment: `gradient` takes finite differences. It's not doing function changing or composition.  What argument does it take?  an array or a function?  Don't fudge the docs.

Comment: @hpaulj I didn't fudge the docs. What exactly is your objection? All arguments to `np.gradient` are arrays, and I'm aware that it takes finite differences, which should be clear from the text at the end of my question.

Comment: @pretzlstyle. Can you provide an example of `A` and `y` please?

Comment: code is available on line, as is `np.diff` (which just uses a sliced difference.  Multidimensional is the complicating factor.  But I can't explore this in more depth for a couple off days.

Answer (score 0):

*(Not an answer to solve the problem)*

> I only get grad1=grad2 for a few simple linear functions

For sure:

```
# np.gradient(f) is equivalent to:
>>> np.gradient(f, np.arange(f.size))
array([24. , 17.5, 37.5, 64. ])

# np.gradient(x) is equivalent to:
>>> np.gradient(x, np.arange(x.size))
array([4. , 2.5, 2.5, 4. ])

# so np.gradient(f) / np.gradient(x) is equivalent to:
>>> np.gradient(f, np.arange(f.size)) / np.gradient(x, np.arange(f.size))
array([ 6.,  7., 15., 16.])
```

If `x` is evenly spaced, `grad1` is equal to `grad2` even if the function `f` is not linear:

```
x = np.array([1, 3, 5, 7])
f = x**2
grad1 = np.gradient(f, x)
grad2 = np.gradient(f) / np.gradient(x)
```

Output:

```
>>> grad1 == grad2
array([ True,  True,  True,  True])
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! But, this isn't consistent with my observations... I think that `x` being monotonic is not the only requirement, but also that `x` be uniformly spaced, as yours is. The `x` I provided in my example was intentionally non-uniformly spaced. Do you agree?

Comment: The thing is though, `np.gradient` does not, in general, assume the input coordinates `x` to be uniform. But I think this expression of the chain rule does, which I suspect is implicit in the call `np.gradient(x)`. When we call `np.gradient(f, x)` with nonuniform `x`, we are really performing an interpolation for each interior point, rather than a true centered-difference...

Comment: @pretzlstyle. You are right "monotonic" is a necessary but not sufficient condition rather than "evenly spaced" is sufficient.